# Approver and Submitter Same Person in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to identify situations in a vacation booking database where an approver and submitter are the same person.  Data looks like this:

```
TIME    VACATION BOOKING    ACTION  NAME
1:00:00        1            SUBMIT  Mike
1:01:00        1            APPROVE Mike
1:02:00        2            SUBMIT  Jane
1:03:00        2            APPROVE Mike
```

Is "Count" the most efficient way to do this in SQL Queries?

I would want to "catch" the Mike results in Vacation Booking 1 above.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work,

Comment: Does the vacation booking column identify the vacation request?

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use count, but I would prefer a self-join

```
SELECT * FROM Bookings B1
INNER JOIN Bookings B2
  ON B1.[Vacation Booking]= B2.[Vacation Booking]
    AND B1.Action = 'SUBMIT'
    AND B2.Action = 'APPROVE'
    AND B1.Name = B2.Name
```